# How to show plt.axhline in both subplots from a for loop in python 3

Tags: python, pandas

Below code is to create two parameter subplots of data per pdf page and I'm using the 'axhline' function to plot the data limits of each parameter. However when I use it inside the for loop, only the second subplot had the data limits - the first one always doesn't show. I suppose what happens is axhline works one at a time in the for loop? Instead of having it in both subplots by end of the for loop? Please have a look in my code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    ax = ax.flatten()
    for i, col in enumerate(hib_list[0:2]):
        ax1 = sns.boxplot(x=lotid, y=cc_df[col], ax=ax[i], hue=temp)
        ax1.set_ylabel(col,fontsize=8)
        ax1.get_legend().remove()
        plt.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
        #Below line is to set data limits
        plt.axhline(y=500, color='r', linestyle='--')
    pdf.savefig()
    plt.close()
```

[image: Output figure as below:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a corrected version of your code. You can set once per loop `ax=axes[i]` and then use `ax` for all operations. `plt.(…)` works only on the last plotted axes object.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
axes = axes.flatten()
for i, col in enumerate(hib_list[0:2]):
    ax = axes[i]
    sns.boxplot(x=lotid, y=cc_df[col], ax=ax, hue=temp)
    ax.set_ylabel(col,fontsize=8)
    ax.get_legend().remove()
    #Below line is to set data limits
    ax.axhline(y=500, color='r', linestyle='--')
plt.tight_layout(pad=1.0)
pdf.savefig()
plt.close()
```